# Adding UITextfield to UITableviewCell causes detailTextLabel to slide "up"

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to add a UITextField as the contentView of a UITableViewcell. It works, and the field has focus, but the detailTextLabel slides up 10px. What's the deal here? As a secondary question, is there a better way to create an in-line edtiable UITableViewCell?

Here's my code. I'm trying to do this as result of a double tap on a tableview cell. I retrieve the actual cell that was tapped like this:

```
CGPoint swipeLocation = [recognizer locationInView:self.tableView];
NSIndexPath *swipedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:swipeLocation];
UITableViewCell *swipedCell;
```

Then I try to add my textfield like this:

```
swipedCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:swipedIndexPath];
NSInteger indent = swipedCell.indentationWidth;
UITextField * newText = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(indent, swipedCell.contentView.frame.origin.y, swipedCell.contentView.frame.size.width, swipedCell.contentView.frame.size.height)];
newText.font = swipedCell.textLabel.font;
newText.text = swipedCell.textLabel.text;
newText.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
newText.autoresizingMask =  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
swipedCell.textLabel.text = @"";
[swipedCell addSubview:newText];
[newText becomeFirstResponder];
```

Not entirely unlike yours, except that when I apply your code, both my text and the detaillabel end up in the center of the cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without out seeing your code it's difficult to know what's going on. Here's the code I use to make a UITextField as a contentView cell that works without issue, hopefully it helps.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TaxCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
CGFloat optionalRightMargin = 10.0;
CGFloat optionalBottomMargin = 10.0;
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(275, 10, cell.contentView.frame.size.width - 270 - optionalRightMargin, cell.contentView.frame.size.height - 10 - optionalBottomMargin)];


textField.placeholder = @"Placeholder";
textField.delegate = self;
textField.autoresizingMask =  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;

textField.text = @"Textfield text"
cell.textLabel.text = @"Textlabel text"
cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Detail text";
[cell.contentView addSubview:textField];

return cell; }
```

Comment: It seems thats it easier to build the textfield into the cell when its created than later. Its working ok now. Thanks